# Cleaning the packages folder after deploy

Tags: azure, nuget, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Website configured to deploy from a Bitbucket repository. This works fine.

Since the application is still in active development, I update the nuget packages it uses quite frequently. This causes the `packages` folder to keep growing indefinitely, unless I go and manually delete the packages.

Now, in my local machine this is not a big issue. Space is cheap. But in Azure, this makes us go over the quota really fast, as old packages accumulate.

How can I customize the Azure deploy process so that it deletes all the packages after a successful deployment?

(I am open to other solutions as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the custom deployment script feature where you add a step that cleans up the `packages` directory.

You can read about it here:
http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38418009331/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart2/

Another option is to add a post deployment action, by adding a script file (.cmd/.bat) that has the clenup logic to the following directory in your site: `d:\home\site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions\`, this script will run after the deployment completes successfully.

Read more about it here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks

Comment: The second option was easier. I created a batch file with just one line: `rd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\packages" /s/q`

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it just worked fine here in my free account (F1) in azure.
Steps:

- Create a .bat file under `C:\home\site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions\myscript.bat`
- Add the content below to your file: (please make sure to insert your TMP folder in the "folder" variable.

```
    set folder="C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy"
    cd /d %folder%
    del *.zip /F /Q 
    for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```